# Form Validation while using Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I am setting the postal_code field as required before the form is submitted.

```
<input id="postal_code" ng-model="postal_code" class="field" ng-
minlength="6" ng-maxlength="18"  ng-pattern="phoneNumberFormat"  required >
```

The postal_code field is auto populated based on the address entered by the user using Google Maps API as below

```
<input type="text" id="autocomplete" onFocus="geolocate()" name= "address" 
ng-model="address" class="input-medium search-query"  ng-minlength="18" ng-
maxlength = "210" >
```

However, when the zip code is populated from the API, the required field of the zipcode is never set to false and currently unable to submit the form. As the field is editable - the required check is needed.

Comment: What happens if you put `ng-required='!postal_code'` instead of `required`?

Comment: It still does not let me submit the form despite the postal_code field already being populated

Comment: Then i'm afraid you hit the autocomplete wall which is not solvable by the framework as browsers aren't firing the change event on autocomplete. Old issue which is closed but not solved as it's not the framework issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1460